# OpenVPN & Juniper SSG-140

Tags: vpn, router, openvpn, juniper, screenos

I asked this question over on some Juniper Forums but they seem to be pretty dead as in over a week it hasn't had that many hits and no one has had any advice.  I figure if I can find someone familiar with Juniper routers they can direct me into the right direction and perhaps I can get this working.

I have three Juniper routers in Production.  Two of them are SSG-5's one is an SSG-140.  I am running ScreenOS 6.3.0r2.0

My issue probably is pretty simple but I am a bit lost.  I set-up an OpenVPN server in Dallas and configured my juniper to pass traffic from the 10.3.21.0 subnet (my OpenVPN subnet) to the Dallas SSG-5.  With my configuration I can hop on OpenVPN and access servers in Dallas.  I did the same thing on our SSG-5 here in Meridian, Texas and those on the OpenVPN can talk to here and Dallas.

I am trying to do the same thing for our Colorado office, and apparently I am missing something.  I know the Juniper VPN between Dallas and Colorado works because I can hop on a server in Dallas and access servers in Colorado but I am unable to access anything across OpenVPN.

I have checked my OpenVPN settings and they seem correct so perhaps I have a routing issue somewhere on the Juniper.  I really don't know where to start as I had a consultant help with the Juniper install but we are a non-profit and can't afford going back to the consultant so I was hoping some of you guys could assist.

Thank You very much in advance, please let me know whatever configs I need to post here to help you guys better.

Comment: Where there any error messages when trying to make the openvpn connection from Colorado on either the client or server?  Can you bump up the error logging on both sides to be more verbose?

Comment: There are no OpenVPN Errors.  I am guessing the issue is something blocking on the Juniper, though I have checked the policies and nothing stands out.  Does anyone know of any quick Juniper commands I can run in the CLI to see if anything is being rejected when I try to ping subnets on the inside. 

The actual VPN connection between Dallas and Colorado is fine (juniper to juniper) the issue is for users coming in through the OpenVPN server.

Comment: Are you using a tunneled or bridged VPN?